# Windows: как посчитать использование CPU для каждого процесса?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wmi

Столкнулся с очередным затыком в winapi. Совершенно не пойму как нормально посчитать использование CPU для процесса. Вроде делаю всё как для linux части, но в винде получаются какие-то дикие степени. Для linux я считаю так:

- читаю [`/proc/$pid/stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)
- беру 14 и 15 параметры - `utime` и `stime`, это использование CPU  в тиках в режиме ядра и в user mode, делю на `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` и получаю количество секунд, затраченное процессом на работу.
- считаю количество секунд, которое процесс работает
- делю первое на второе, умножаю на 100 и всё

В windows тоже можно получить utime и stime. Я делаю это через wmi из класса [Win32_Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx) и там эти параметры называются `UserModeTime` и `KernelModeTime`. Только вот совершенно не понятно что это за единицы - `100 nanosecond units`. Пытаюсь перевести в секунды - то получаются какие-то дикие степени, то время, затраченное CPU больше чем вообще время работы (его беру из `CreationDate`). Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась не там, где я её искал. Параметры `UserModeTime` и `KernelModeTime` класса `Win32_Process` имеют тип `uint64`, это понятно из описания. Получить данные оттуда можно используя специальный тип данных [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx). Подробнее как это работает [в примере](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa390418(v=vs.85).aspx). Проблема была в получении данных именно типа `uint64`. Кто бы мог подумать, что `uint64` будет хранится как строка несмотря на то, что в `VARIANT` есть 8 байтовый integer. Правильное получение `uint64` из `VARIANT` будет выглядеть как-то так ([вот тут](https://github.com/reklatsmasters/node-process-list/blob/2aab289870ce202467d3c8fd8bb8e40a2560cbf5/src/win/tasklist.cpp#L436) полый рабочий код):

```
VARIANT prop;
// some code ...
uint64_t myvar = _wtoi64(prop.bstrVal);
```

А чтоб конвертировать из 100-nanosecond units в миллисекунды, можно воспользоваться [вот этим](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979590(v=vs.85).aspx) примером из документации